# node.js code to append data to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I append data to a file using node.js

I already have a file named myfile.json with data. I want to check if the file name exists and then append some data to that file.

I'm using following code

```
var writeTempFile = function (reportPath, data, callback) {   
    fs.writeFile(reportPath, data, function (err) {
        //if (err) //say(err);
        callback(err);
    });
}
writeTempFile(reportDir + '_' + query.jobid + ".json", data, function (err) {
    context.sendResponse(data, 200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
```

Comment: There is one issue: You can't truly append data to a file of JSON format while preserving the format. You would have to read the data, parse it as JSON, edit the JSON and add your data, and then write the JSON back to the file.

Comment: How can it is possible in code wise?

Comment: It really depends on your JSON structure and what data you are trying to append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jsonfile

```
var jf = require('jsonfile');
var yourdata;
var file = '/tmp/data.json';
jf.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
    if(!err) {
        var finalData = merge(obj, yourdata);

        jf.writeFile(file, finalData, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```

You need to implement your merging logic in merge(object1, object2)

https://npmjs.org/package/jsonfile

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code.

```
function addToFile(reportPath, data, callback){
    fs.appendFile(reportPath, data, function (err) {
        callback(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: iam getting this error` fs.appendFile(reportPath, data, function (err)
         ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'appendFile'
`

Answer (score 0):

**Node offers fs module to work with file system.**
To use this module do

```
var fs = require('fs')
```

To append some data to file you can do:

```
fs.appendFile('message.txt', 'data to append', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
 console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
});
```

Node offers you both synchronous and asynchronous method to append data to file, For more information please refer to this [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)

Comment: am getting `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'appendFile'
`

Comment: @Sush you might be using an old version of Node.js if you are getting that error.

Comment: my node version is v0.6.12

Comment: Purely a guess, but I think a lot of the `fs` stuff changed around 0.9ish. Prior to that it has a lot of cross-platform issues (not to say that it's void of them now).
It's on v0.10.24 now.

Comment: @Sush use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to upgrade it to the latest. It should be working after that.